# SendGrid Attachment generated using Stream shows unprotected

Tags: c#, sendgrid

We have a SendGrid Trial version.
Platform: C#
We send Email with attachment using below code.

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
email.AddAttachmentAsync("Sample.doc", memoryStream, "application/msword", "attachment", "Banner");
Task<Response> ts = sendGridClient.SendEmailAsync(email);
```

Attachment are properly attached with mail but when we open-up doc file, it is showing us Protected view warning at a place where we have an image(
[SendGrid-Stream-To-Doc-unprotected-view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JJ57.png) )

Is it happening due to We have a trial version or something else?

Comment: The SendGrid offers a Debug console in your account and you can see the traffic of the Usage and the API calls over there. Please check and add more information, if the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be the email client refusing to open/download the attachment which appears to be an image file. In your email client, look for a setting to download/display images in "this" email to allow the image to be displayed.